# Must NuGet configure project's include paths?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, casablanca, cpprest-sdk

I have downloaded [Dropbox CPP REST sample from official MS site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn342869.aspx). In order to use cpprestsdk I asked NuGet to download package. It has downloaded packages for various tool sets:

[image]

When I build project I got error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'uri.h': No such file or directory    DropboxApp  d:\code_podurirest0813\dropboxapp\dropboxapp\oAuth.h    30
```

uri.h is part of library. I was expecting NuGet set up include paths in project. Do I expect too much or there might be other issues?

UPD

MS Dropbox sample was not happy about changing uri.h to cpprest\uri.h. It can't find new include ither.

Since this reason I have created my own console application and asked NuGet download cpprestsdk. After procedure was done I found that no automatic library and include paths setup was performed:

[image]

```
1>  Creating directory "D:\Code_PoduriREST0813\2012\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\".
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Creating "Debug\ConsoleApplication1.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>ClCompile:
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  ConsoleApplication1.cpp
1>d:\code_podurirest0813\2012\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cpprest\uri.h': No such file or directory
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I was expecting NuGet set up include paths in project. Do I expect too much or there might be other issues?

No, after installed that package, NuGet would set the header files and library paths automatically, no need to add them manually. But we should carefully how to include the header file. You will notice that there are two subfolder "`cpprest`", "pplx" in the "`include`" folder. So we should use "`cpprest\uri.h`" to include the header file:

[image]

So please check the way of including the header file in the project.

**Update:**

I have noticed the difference is that the version of your Visual Studio is 2012 (the default version of NuGet is 2.8.6), my Visual Studio is 2015(The version of NuGet is 3.4.4). Then I test it on the Visual Studio 2012 and 2013, only failed on Visual Studio 2012, not sure why the old version of NuGet(2.8.6) could not setup library and header paths automatically. However, we could not use the new version of NuGet in Visual Studio 2012, so to resolve this issue, **we have to add the path of library and header file manually or you can update you Visual Studio to 2013 and later.**

Comment: Setting cpprest\uri.h not helped in my case. I have updated message body with more details

Comment: @vico, Thanks for your reply. I have found out the reason for this issue is the old version of NuGet. To resolve this issue, we have to add the path manually or update your Visual Studio to 2013 and later.